# strange error message: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, graph

I have a strange problem with a code I'm trying to run on jupyter notebook(python version - 3.7.6)

the code in this link (https://towardsdatascience.com/to-all-data-scientists-the-one-graph-algorithm-you-need-to-know-59178dbb1ec2) was kind of out of date because of the python version it was written on. I changed the ".iteritems" to ".items" and it worked well up to this part:

```
graph = Graph(g)
graph.add_edge(("Mumbai", "Delhi"),400)
graph.add_edge(("Delhi", "Kolkata"),500)
graph.add_edge(("Kolkata", "Bangalore"),600)
graph.add_edge(("TX", "NY"),1200)
graph.add_edge(("ALB", "NY"),800)

g = graph.adj_mat()

def bfs_connected_components(graph):
    connected_components = []
    nodes = graph.keys()

    while len(nodes)!=0:
        start_node = nodes.pop()
        queue = [start_node] #FIFO
        visited = [start_node]
        while len(queue)!=0:
            start = queue[0]
            queue.remove(start)
            neighbours = graph[start]
            for neighbour,_ in neighbours.items():
                if neighbour not in visited:
                    queue.append(neighbour)
                    visited.append(neighbour)
                    nodes.remove(neighbour)
        connected_components.append(visited)

    return connected_components

print bfs_connected_components(g)
```

It gives me this error `File "<ipython-input-48-660b0e10e666>", line 32 print bfs_connected_components(g) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

So i tried to take off `print` and let just `bfs_connected_components(g)` to find what the debugger would return me.

When I run the code without the `print` command it returns me the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-09c142e436e3> in <module>
     30     return connected_components
     31 
---> 32 bfs_connected_components(g)

<ipython-input-49-09c142e436e3> in bfs_connected_components(graph)
     14 
     15     while len(nodes)!=0:
---> 16         start_node = nodes.pop()
     17         queue = [start_node] #FIFO
     18         visited = [start_node]

AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

which is weird, because there is `.pop` commands in the previous codes in this link and it worked well without any errors, except for the `.iteritems` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other issues you mentioned (such as the missing parentheses in `print`, and the items to iteritems change), this is a Python version issue. In Python 3, pop doesn't work on dict_keys.

To work around this, you can make it a list. In your code, do `nodes = list(graph.keys())`.